# how do I share a class between ASP .NET and Framework 4.6 applications?

Tags: c#, project, share

I have two projects. One is targeted to Framework 4.6, another to .NET 6.0
When I try to create a reference, compiler produces an error "Project '..\Common\Common.csproj' targets '.NET6.0'. It cannot be referenced by a project that targets '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6'

How would you overcome the problem?

Comment: Newer version of .Net cannot be used in older versions of .Net.

Comment: Thank you! I got it, but how to achieve the goal... Should I just maintain 2 copies of the class?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can share a library if you build it for [.NET Standard](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/platform/dotnet-standard).  To share a .NET Standard 2.0 library you'll need to target at least .NET Framework 4.6.1, which will be fine unless you need to deploy to Windows Vista or Windows Server 2008, which are both long out-of-support.

[image]

Comment: I think it needs to be Standard 1.3, that's the highest that supports both Framework 4.6 and .Net 6

Comment: 4.6.1 is out of support, if you're on a supported Windows patch level, you can use .NET Standard 2.0. https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/net-framework-4-5-2-4-6-4-6-1-will-reach-end-of-support-on-april-26-2022/

Comment: As per the link, the problem was that 4.6 I tried to use was not supported by Standard 2.0 and there was no 1.3. At the end I move it up to 4.6.1 and with Standard 2.0 my referenced projects now do see namespace of the shared one. You saved my day! David and gunr2171, thank you both a lot!